# Trying to avoid multiple calls to jQuery in a Domino XPage

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, dojo, xpages

I am attempting to use the '[DataTables](https://datatables.net/)' table plug-in for jQuery on a simple Domino XPage.

I have loaded the two required libraries from CDN's...

JQuery: ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js

DataTables: cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css

I have also tried loading them from local resources (doesn't help).

I then prepare a basic table on my XPage, and include the necessary Javascript to initialise the table...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tableID').DataTable();
} );
```

When I test the XPage, I continually observe

```
test.xsp:15 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
```

I've searched through several forums, and the general consensus is that...

a) I have loaded the libraries in the wrong order (nope!)

b) I have loaded jQuery more than once (how?)

I have many other solutions using Bootstrap and jQuery, and have never run into this issue before. So, I though I might strip the XPage back to bare bones. I got rid of all Dojo elements on the page by adding the following line to the 'xp.properties' file...

```
xsp.client.script.libraries=none
```

That actually seemed to work! I no longer observed the error. However, my page no longer looked like it should (for obvious reasons!). I've had to restore the 'xp.properties' file back to its original state, but cannot find out how to avoid the error.

Has anyone successfully used the 'DataTables' jQuery plug-in on an XPage? Any feedback or suggestions would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes I have been doing a load of work on DataTables in XPages so it definitely works! I know your pain though....
The order of your jquery scripts in relation to each other may be okay, however there is a clash with dojo and it's AMD loader, so you have 3 options.

Option 1. Load your jquery scripts before any of the xpages scripts

Option 2. remove the 'amd loader' just before your jquery scripts and then restore it just after

Option 3. modify the javascript of the datatables so it ignores the amd problem

**Option 1 : Loading your jQuery scripts first**

If you are using resource aggregation, you can use this tip from Sven Hasselbach's blog, in which you use the generic 'headTag' resource tag and it will load first.
http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1181

If you want a solution that will work regardless of resource aggregation setting, I have an example on my blog in which you can create a viewRootRenderer which will then allow you to specify that you want a script loaded BEFORE everything else
http://camerongregor.com/2016/09/19/controlling-the-order-of-script-resources-e-g-jquery-with-a-custom-viewrootrenderer/

**Option 2. Removing the AMD loader before loading scripts**

There is an xsnippet which explains how to remove and then restore the amd loader so that a jquery plugin will load
https://openntf.org/xsnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=hack-to-use-jquery-amd-widgets-and-dojo-together

Sven had already made a similar solution to mine above (viewRootRenderer) in which you can specify which scripts will need the amd loader disabled and it will do this for you, it is available here
http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=2070

**Option 3 : modify javascript of the jquery plugin (datatables)**

Mark Roden demonstrated this on his blog. I don't really like doing it but hey it works!
https://xomino.com/category/jquery-in-xpages/

Let me know if any of this works! I hope I'm right, with javascript I never know...

Comment: Thanks so much Cameron! You were spot on, and you've really helped me get over this hurdle. Funny thing is, I remember reading a couple of those blog posts back when they were first released - wasn't familiar with the context though, so it never occurred to me that they applied here.

So far, the easiest route has been to use Sven's 'headTag' resource tag - worked perfectly (so far).

Cheers mate!

Comment: No worries Terry, I remember feeling the same that there were bits and pieces of this problem on several different blogs etc. I used headTag and option 3 modify javascript a lot, but now have moved on to implement the custom viewRootrenderer so that I don't have to worry about aggregation. Glad that it help