# Xpages adds only 1 jquery library instead of 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, xpages

Hating XPages and all the stuff related to IBM so much I'm struggling with this "PERFECT" IDE and technology again. Initially I've written a HTML page to 'translate' it to 'much better' XHTML after finishing with basic functionality. My page uses 2 JQuery libraries, `jquery-min` and `jquery-ui` respectively. But it really doesn't 'see' the jquery-ui library. When I'm trying to access it like `localhost:8080\resources\jquery-ui.js` it works so well, but it cannot be used on a page for some reason. The exception I'm getting is `xxx.dialog()` is not a function - absolutely the same exception which I get if I remove `jquery-ui.js` library from `<script>` tag in ordinary HTML.

The way I add these libraries on a page is like that:

```
<xp:this.resources>
        <xp:script src="unp/jquery-ui.js" clientSide="true"/>
        <xp:script src="unp/jquery-min.js" clientSide="true"/>
        <xp:styleSheet href="/jquery-ui.css" />
</xp:this.resources>
```

And `jquery-min.js` works so well, but `jquery-ui.js` is totally ignored. How is it possible?

Comment: I haven't worked with jQuery UI in XPages, so I'm not sure if it will cause conflicts since XPages is using Dojo. But where did you store the jQuery UI files? From that prefix (unp/) it looks like you've been working with Unplugged. Can you access them using a url like <server>/<your nsf path>/unp/jquery-ui.js?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41712753/2065611

Comment: Maybe you should quit your job if it is so frustrating for you.

Answer (score 3):

The jQueryu UI js file fails to load because it uses AMD loading. So remove the AMD loading part from jquery-ui.js by changing the following in the jquery-ui.js file:

```
if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
```

to this:

```
if ( typeof define === "function" && false ) {
```

Comment: There's a line {"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],t). Changed to {"function"==typeof define&&false?define(["jquery"],t), but nothing has changed :c